# Ruby on Rails console - undefined method `assets'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On the project the console ceased to be started, I tried everything that found in Google..

I run `rails c` and get an error:

```
/Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:97:in `method_missing': undefined method `assets' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fae6a9bdf78>
Did you mean?  asset_host (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/popper_js-1.12.9/lib/popper_js/engine.rb:6:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/gorbunov/Projects/buktopuha_api/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:102:in `preload'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I don't know what to do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `assets` method is undefined in your `config/application.rb` , try to remove it.

Comment: Check this line `from /Users/gorbunov/Projects/buktopuha_api/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'`

Comment: You can refer the following thread this may help you https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web/issues/46

Comment: @rails_id there is no assets method in config/application.rb

Comment: @AkashPinnaka only this: `Rails.application.initialize!`

Comment: Do you have `sass-rails`, `jquery-rails`, `uglifier` installed? also in `application.rb` add the line `require "sprockets/railtie"` and check if it works.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem and found the solution [here](https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web/issues/46#issuecomment-273975173), which was to ensure you have the sprockets line in config/application.rb

```rb
require "rails"
 require "active_model/railtie"
 require "active_job/railtie"
 require "active_record/railtie"
 require "active_storage/engine"
 require "action_controller/railtie"
 require "action_mailer/railtie"
 require "action_mailbox/engine"
 require "action_text/engine"
 require "action_view/railtie"
 require "action_cable/engine"
 require "sprockets/railtie"  # <--- make sure this line is here
 require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Note that the above lines differ a little between rails versions. Find what it should look like for your rails version at the rails guide for your version. [Here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/initialization.html#railties-lib-rails-all-rb)'s rails 6.1, and [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/initialization.html#railties-lib-rails-all-rb)'s 7.0.

---

Funnily enough, I had just removed `require "sprockets/railtie"` since I was trying to [remove sprockets](https://andre.arko.net/2020/07/09/rails-6-with-webpack-in-appassets-and-no-sprockets/). In any case, I put it back in and rails is happy again.

Answer (score 2):

To add to this answer, you'll also need this in your gemfile

```
gem 'sprockets-rails'
```